# Apache error logs are empty httpd.conf defines the error log file in /var/log/httpd/error_log

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

I am relatively new to server administration and log files, so I am not sure what's wrong here. But here is what's going on. I am a PHP developer and I often navigate to `/var/log/httpd/error_log.{date}` when there is an error, since the log files give detailed information.

I am running `Apache/2.2.3` and `Linux 2.6.18-164.el5 i686`

However, since the last time I accessed the server (August 29th), I tried opening the logs just today because I came across a PHP error. However, the logs are completely empty.

The following files are in the /var/log/httpd folder:

- access_log
- access.log
- error_log
- ssl_access_log
- ssl_error_log
- ssl_request_log

All of these files are empty. I looked at `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and found the following:

```
#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
#ErrorLog logs/error_log
ErrorLog "|/bin/rotatelogs /var/log/httpd/error_log.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 100M"
```

I remember the last time error_log file was showing the errors, the file name was something along the lines of `error_log.2014-08-29-15_20_05`

Some people were helpful enough to try to help me in the chat rooms, but we were unable to solve it.

Is there some kind of setting that I am unaware of that would enable the logs again?

Please let me know if I need to add anymore details.

Comment: Please specify your distribution. Are these the stock binary packages for your distribution, a local install, or something else?

Comment: I am not sure how to answer that question, as I am relatively new to server administration. Is there some kind of bash command I can run to provide you with the information?

Comment: Run `lsb_release -a`  for the distribution and version. As for whether you are using binary packages etc. for apache, don't you know?

Comment: No, I am not the manager for the server, so I don't usually deal with the servers directly. However, in this case, I have to do it myself. The person who deals with the server only told me that "Logs may have been disabled". I don't know what that means or how you enable it. Here are the results for that command: `LSB Version:    :core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.1-ia32:graphics-3.1-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)
Release:        5.4
Codename:       Tikanga`

Comment: Well, in that case, the manager really should be taking care of this. A simple suggestion. Install the distribution in question somewhere else. Then compare the two. If this machine has been messed with, you should be able to see the differences.